# Conditional doesn´t return True when it is proved that it is in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, integer

I am trying to find if an integer value exists in a DataFrame column:

When I try `df[df['COLUMN'] == 196930]`, I get the rows of the DataFrame containing the column value as expected.

However, I am running into problems trying to use a conditional to find if the value is the column (and ultimately perform an action based on this condition):

```
if 196930 in df['COLUMN']:
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

It returns `False` even though this integer clearly exists in the DataFrame column, and I don't understand why this is happening. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df['COLUMN']` returns a pandas Series. For the `in` operator, the Series class returns true if there is a **label** matching the operand. When you write `if 196930 in df['COLUMN']` you are testing if the Series contains the label 196930.

You can test if the column contains the **value** like this:

```py
if (df['COLUMN'] == 196930).any(): ...

if df['COLUMN'].eq(196930).any(): ...
```